# how to get value of column2 when column 1 is greater 3 and check this value belong to which Bin

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe with two columns , A and B . first i need to make empty bins with step 1 from 1 to 11 , (1,2),(2,3)....(10,11). then check from original dataframe if column B value greater than 3 then get value of column 'A' 2 rows before when column B is greater than 3.

```
Here is example dataframe :
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,8.5,5.2,7,8,9,0,4,5,6],'B':[1,2,2,2,3.1,3.2,3,2,1,2]})

Required output 1:
df_out1=pd.DataFrame({'Value_A':[8.5,5.2]})

Required_output_2:

df_output2:

Bins    count
(1 2)    0    
(2,3)    0
(3,4)    0
(4,5)    0
(5,6)    1
(6,7)    0
（7,8）  0
（8,9）  1  
（9,10）  0
（10,11） 0
```

Comment: was there some code you tried and failed?

Comment: @sammywemmy so far didn't find the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can index on a shifted series to get the two rows before 'A' satisfies some condition like

```
out1 = df['A'].shift(3)[df['B'] > 3]
```

The thing you want to do with the bins is known as a histogram. You can easily do this with numpy like

```
count, bin_edges = np.histogram(out1, bins=[i for i in range(1, 12)])

out2 = pd.DataFrame({'bin_lo': bin_edges[:-1], 'bin_hi': bin_edges[1:], 'count': count})
```

Here 'bin_lo' and 'bin_hi' are the lower and upper bounds of the bins.